# Minimizing preamble needed with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I use xetex and fontspec to work with custom fonts like this:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{AGaramondPro}[Path = fonts/garamond/,%
  BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular.otf,
  RawFeature={%
    +onum  % odd style figures
}]
\newfontfamily{\special}[Path = fonts/garamond/,%
  BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular.otf,
  RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{AGaramondPro}
```

I keep asking myself if i can DRY it, so i define the font only once.

The font above is just an example. I have other fonts, where i would like to enable/disable certain RawFeatures for all instances without copy-pasting everywhere...

So the goal is that i can do something like

```
lorem {\ttfamily ipsum \special{dolor} amet}
```

and `dolor` is then set in Garamond small capitals, and not in mono.

Comment: Why do you do this definition of `\Mono`? You can use `\ttfamily` instead. Specific settings can be changed later on using `\addfontfeatures`.

Comment: Could you please make some example which features you actually try to enable/disable? Have you looked into the documentation (including the points on `\addfontfeatures`)?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: Do *not* redefine the command `\special`!  That is a very important TeX primitive.

Comment: my googlefu is insufficient. Havent been able to find the implications of redefineing `\special`. @HenriMenke what happens though?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the repetitious code into a file such as `GaramondPro.fontspec` and then load that more than once with modifications.  The [documentation gives the example](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#15) of `My Charis.fontspec` containing the lines:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[My Charis]
{
  Extension = .ttf ,
  UprightFont = CharisSILR,
  BoldFont = CharisSILB,
  ItalicFont = CharisSILI,
  BoldItalicFont = CharisSILBI,
  % <any other desired options>
}
```